# S3 bucket name gets added to the S3 endpoint

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

When trying to access a file from a S3 bucket using Scala, the bucket name gets added to the front of endpoint and the endpoint becomes wrong and in-accessible.

Libraries:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.0"
```

Code:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "[endpoint]")
sc.textFile("s3a://[bucket_name]/testa.txt")
```

Comment: Your "endpoint" isn't `s3[-region].amazonaws.com`?

Comment: No, it's a custom endpoint and not *.amazonaws.com.

Comment: So, not actually S3, then, but something S3-compatible?

Comment: No, it's actually S3 provided by NetApp installed in own servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling the [path style URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) solves the issue as there are no virtual hosts configuration done on the server where S3 is installed. `fs.s3a.path.style.access`([docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)) can be set to true to enable path style URLs.

Comment: I am running into same issue. But I have the path style access enabled. ```spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")```. But my code is failing at ```AmazonHttpClient not able to execute test-bucket.s3-region0.myobjectStore.com``` This means the path style access is not being picked up.

Comment: You also need to change the URL from a virtual hosted style URL to a path style URL. The format of the virtual hosted style URL is `https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key name`. And the format of the path-style URL is `https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key name`. In your case, the bucket name should not be a part of the domain name in the URL, and so `fs.s3a.endpoint` should be set as `${protocol}://s3-region0.myobjectStore.com`, where the `protocol` is either `https` or `http`.